# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestListener

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am not an expert in java. I am trying to run a test by converting eclipse .java file in to runnable jar using export command and when I run this .jar at command prompt using `$java -jar myfile.jar` it shows me following error.

I would really appreciate help in resolving this issue.

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestListener 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestListener 
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) 
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ... 3 more
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestListener
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.ITestListener
 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
 ... 3 more

Comment: I can send the code if needed. Stack Overflow did not allowed me to post the code due some formatting ...

Comment: Please post the code as well to further investigate the issue.

Comment: When you run a JAR file you need to provide the external JARS that are required in runtime to execute the program. Those JAR files are kept in a path called CLASSPATH and you need to pass the CLASSPATH while running the JAR file. In this way , the external JARS are loaded in application classpath.

Comment: I did not quite get your point ... kindly elaborate more .... I am using mac terminal to run jar file ...

Comment: How do I share the code .... ? This comment portion allow only limited number of characters

Comment: You can edit your post.

Comment: Is this file/calss org/testng/ITestListener is part of your code?

Comment: not sure how add my code here ... I tried to edit the this post using edit(1) link .. but it was disable to add anything ... this editor sucks .. not sure why it asks to format the code ...? and it did not allowed my to put code in my original post itself

Comment: Is this file/calss org/testng/ITestListener is part of your code? My answer Yes

Comment: Jeeshan Bhai, here is not enough space to paste the code ... pl send me you email or any media where we can chat .. need to resolve this problem if you can help